# Showing related items in a form with annotations

Tags: php, forms, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have got a question regarding populating my form with entities form a many to many relation.

First my code:

**Product Entity:**

```
<?php
namespace My\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Zend\Form\Annotation;
use My\Entity\Brand;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="My\EntityRepository\Product")
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 * @Annotation\Hydrator("Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ArraySerializable")
 * @Annotation\Name("Product")
 */
class Product{

    /**
     * @ORM\id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Annotation\Attributes({"type":"hidden"})
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="productGroup")
     * @Annotation\Type("Zend\Form\Element\Select")
     * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Productgroup: "})
     */
    protected $productGroups;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(nullable=false)
     * @Annotation\Attributes({"type":"text"})
     * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Product name:"})
     */
    protected $productName;

    /**
     * @Annotation\Attributes({"type":"textarea"})
     * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Product description: "})
     * @ORM\Column
     */
    protected $description;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->memos = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->productGroups = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Sets the product tags
     * @param ArrayCollection $tags
     */
    public function setTags(\Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $tags) {
        $this->productGroups = $tags;
    }


    /**
     * This function unsets a product group
     */
    public function unsetProductsGroups() {
        unset($this->productGroups);
    }
}
```

**Then I have My Action**

```
 public function newAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();

        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $product = new Product();
        $builder = new AnnotationBuilder($em);
        $form = $builder->createForm($product);


        if ($request->isPost() && $this->request->getPost()) {
            $repo = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('My\Entity\Product');
            $repo->addProduct($this->getRequest()->getPost());
            $this->flashMessenger()->addMessage('The product was added.');
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('zfcadmin');
        } else {
            $config = $this->getModuleConfig();
            if (isset($config['my_form_extra'])) {
                foreach ($config['my_form_extra'] as $field) {
                    $form->add($field);
                }
            }

            $form->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($em, 'My\Entity\Product'));
            $form->bind($product);
            return new ViewModel(array('form' => $form));
        }
    }
```

**And my View**

```
<div class="well">
    <?php
        $form = $this->form;
        $form->setAttribute('method','post');
        echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
        echo $this->formSelect($form->get('productGroups'));
        echo $this->form()->closeTag($form);
    ?>
</div>
```

The output of this an empty select box. Even in my edit form where the setup is the same but the dropdown is empty and there are surely related items.

Note: I have only shown the information related to this question.

I would like to know how I can solve this problem whith showing related items. Prefferably only using annotations.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one $product instance shown, it is a new Product with empty memo and productGroup array collections. The form has this un-managed product instance bound to it, your view is getting the form with the un-managed product instance bound, so there are no select items displayed.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. But that was part of my question. When I have an empty product object, it should show all the productGroup items which are in the productGroup table. Also in my edit form, it doesn't show the related items. And there I do have related items.

Comment: If you are trying to create a select element that contains a list of all Product Groups such that an association between Product and Product Group can be made, have a look at the [entity select element](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule/blob/master/src/DoctrineORMModule/Form/Element/EntitySelect.php) provided by the Doctrine ORM ZF2 Module. This will allow you to configure a select element that executes a set of criteria to select product groups (such as find all).